# Polymer animated pages not fully showing on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, polymer, viewport

[Polymer's core animated pages](https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-elements/demo.html#core-animated-pages) isn't working on mobile devices. I tested both the official website and mine with the element and it goes off-screen when selecting the card. Am I forgetting some css or javascript? 
Img example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTT17.jpg

Comment: I believe this is just how they designed it, it has nothing to do with the `core-animated-pages` itself; When you look at the source code, you will see the left side of the card has a fixed 400px width, but the right side only has a padding. The animations themselves are working fine.

Comment: It's possible to edit the element, but what would I need to do to make the card div show fully on the screen?

Comment: Don't quite understand what you mean. For the `hero-transition` used in this example you can transition whatever element on whatever position to whatever element on another position in another `<section>`.